# Work out the MAX of a Python Pandas dataframe within a date range

Tags: python, date, pandas, max

I have a set of stock market data, sampled below.

I would like to like to work out the MAX ‘close’ price over each 5 day period.

```
symbol  date    open    high    low close   volume
AAU 1-Jan-07    2.25    2.25    2.25    2.25    0
AAU 2-Jan-07    2.25    2.25    2.25    2.25    0
AAU 3-Jan-07    2.32    2.32    2.26    2.26    39800
AAU 4-Jan-07    2.29    2.35    2.27    2.32    114200
AAU 5-Jan-07    2.32    2.32    2.26    2.27    113600
AAU 8-Jan-07    2.27    2.35    2.1 2.33    84500
AAU 9-Jan-07    2.31    2.31    2.21    2.23    54200
AAU 10-Jan-07   2.24    2.3 2.2 2.3 29000
AAU 11-Jan-07   2.23    2.33    2.22    2.24    21400
AAU 12-Jan-07   2.25    2.33    2.25    2.33    45200
```

To do this I have added a new column to calculate the end date range (+5 days):

```
df[‘1w_date'] = df[‘date'].shift(-6)
```

The df then looks like this:

```
symbol  date    open    high    low close   volume  5d_date
AAU 1-Jan-07    2.25    2.25    2.25    2.25    0   8-Jan-07
AAU 2-Jan-07    2.25    2.25    2.25    2.25    0   9-Jan-07
AAU 3-Jan-07    2.32    2.32    2.26    2.26    39800   10-Jan-07
AAU 4-Jan-07    2.29    2.35    2.27    2.32    114200  11-Jan-07
AAU 5-Jan-07    2.32    2.32    2.26    2.27    113600  12-Jan-07
AAU 8-Jan-07    2.27    2.35    2.1 2.33    84500   15-Jan-07
AAU 9-Jan-07    2.31    2.31    2.21    2.23    54200   16-Jan-07
AAU 10-Jan-07   2.24    2.3 2.2 2.3 29000   17-Jan-07
AAU 11-Jan-07   2.23    2.33    2.22    2.24    21400   18-Jan-07
AAU 12-Jan-07   2.25    2.33    2.25    2.33    45200   19-Jan-07
```

Next I set the date column as the df Index:

```
df = df.set_index(['date'])
```

Then I attempt to loop through each row using the ‘date’ as the start date and the ‘5d_date’ as the end date.

```
for i in df:
    date_filter = df.loc[df[‘date’]:df[‘5d_date']]
    df[‘min_value'] = min(date_filter['low'])
    df[‘max_value'] = max(date_filter['high'])
```

Unfortunately I get a KeyError: ‘date’.

I have tried many different ways, but cannot figure out how to do this. Does anyone know how to fix this, or a better way of doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set the index to `date`, you can use `pd.DataFrame.rolling`:

```
df.rolling('7d')['close'].mean()
Out[93]: 
    date
2007-01-01    2.250000
2007-01-02    2.250000
2007-01-03    2.253333
2007-01-04    2.270000
2007-01-05    2.270000
2007-01-08    2.286000
2007-01-09    2.282000
2007-01-10    2.290000
2007-01-11    2.274000
2007-01-12    2.286000
Name: close, dtype: float64
```

or, even without doing so,

```
df.rolling(5)['close'].mean()
Out[94]: 
date
2007-01-01      NaN
2007-01-02      NaN
2007-01-03      NaN
2007-01-04      NaN
2007-01-05    2.270
2007-01-08    2.286
2007-01-09    2.282
2007-01-10    2.290
2007-01-11    2.274
2007-01-12    2.286
Name: close, dtype: float64
```

depending on whether you want a week (1), or five rows of data (2).

To have either of these at the start of the range instead of the end, just add `.shift(-4)` to the latter, and even to the former if you really do have exactly five days per week, every week.